# How to count the number of characters of the first line of a string?

Tags: bash

I know how to count the length of a string in bash:

```
var1=$'Title\n\nsome text some text some text some text'
echo "$var1"
length=${#var1}
echo "Length: $length"
```

I also know how to count the number characters in EACH line of a FILE:

```
awk '{ print length($0); }' file
```

but it doesn't work for bash variables, only for files:

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `var1' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

But I would like to count the number of characters in the 1st and 3rd line (or a particular line). Not the length of all of them because the string can be very long. Is it possible?

```
var1=$'Title\n\nsome text some text some text some text'
echo "$var1"
length_of_1st_line=[???]
length_of_3rd_line=[???]
echo "$length_of_1st_line"
echo "$length_of_3rd_line"
```

How can I count the number of characters of the first (or third, or any other given) line of a string variable in bash and keep it in a variable?

Comment: A `HERE-String` gets you part of the way there, i.e. `awk '{ print length($0); }' <<< "$var1"` Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo -e "$var1" | awk 'NR==1 || NR==3 { print length($0); }'
```

Output:

```
5
39
```

Comment: Ok, I have it: `length_of_1st_line=$(echo -e "$var1" | awk 'NR==1 { print length($0); }')`.

Comment: or with sed: `length_of_1st_line=$(echo -e "$var1" | sed '1!d')`

Comment: awk 'NR==1 || NR==3 { print length($0); }' <<<"$var1"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` with a string as input by [cheating](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html#PROCESSSUBREF):

```
$> var1='Title\n\nsome text some text some text some text'
$> awk '{print length($0)}' <(echo -e $var1)
5
0
39
```

Comment: But I only need the length of a particular line, not all of them, because the string can be very long. Is it possible to change your code to print the length of a given line?

Answer (score 0):

Well, with right quoting (:

```
$ awk "BEGIN{print \"$(head -1 <(echo "$var1"))\"}"
Title
```

and with `length`:

```
$ awk "BEGIN{print length(\"$(head -1 <(echo "$var1"))\")}"
5
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive on how does it not work. I tested with 3 different awks in two different systems (all Linux based, though).

Comment: When I wrote the comment you had only the first part of the code in your answer, which prints the string, not the length. After my comment you added the second part, but in my console it shows "46" (which is the length of the whole string), not "5". Even if I change "-1" to "-3" it won't print the length of the third line, so it's not an answer to my question.

Comment: So, what is your system? Also, I missed the req for the third line, sorry about that. This answer does not serve you right.

Comment: Debian, and yours?

Comment: Debian and Ubuntu. Well, @Cyrus' solution is the right way anyway, you should use that one. This was a double quote test for myself.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I count the number of characters of the first (or third, or any other given) line of a string variable in bash and keep it in a variable?

Example 1: (1) store input lines in a string instead of a file; (2) a function that use `sed` to extract a given line of a given string then calculate length of that line; (3) store the results in an array `_len`

```
#!/bin/bash

# lines are stored in a string, not in a file

_string='title
this is the second line
the third line is like this
and this is the forth line, a bit longer
this one shorter'

# function to print length of line $1 of string $2

_lenln() {
  local s=$(sed -n "$1{p;q}" <<<"$2")
  echo ${#s}
}

# test that function, store results in an array _len

_len=()

_len[1]=`_lenln 1 "$_string"`
_len[2]=`_lenln 2 "$_string"`
_len[4]=`_lenln 4 "$_string"`

echo ${_len[1]}
echo ${_len[2]}
echo ${_len[4]}
```

Example 2: (1) store input lines in a string instead of a file; (2) `awk` to calculate length of line 1 and line 3; (3) store the results in an array `_len`

```
#!/bin/bash

_string='title
this is the second line
the third line is like this
and this is the forth line, a bit longer
this one shorter'

_len=()

# awk to contruct bash command that calulate length of line 1 and 3
# then store those results in an array _len

eval $(awk 'NR==1||NR==3{print "_len[" NR "]=" length($0)}' <<<"$_string")

echo ${_len[1]}
echo ${_len[3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use anything external to bash (like awk) for this.

```
$ var1=$'Title\n\nsome text some text some text some text'
$ n=0; while read x; do a[$((++n))]=${#x}; done <<<"$var1"
```

This populates an array, `$a`, with key/value pairs where the key is a line number and the value is the number of characters on that line. Input is read by the loop using a herestring.

From this point, you have multiple options for accessing the contents of the array:

```
$ declare -p a
declare -a a=([1]="5" [2]="0" [3]="39")
$ for (( n=1; n<=${#a[@]}; n++ )); do printf '%d: %d\n' "$n" "${a[$n]}"; done
1: 5
2: 0
3: 39
$ echo "${a[3]}"
39
```

You might want to consider using `read -r` depending on your input.